# Detecting the input of a carriage return in the console

Tags: python, input, carriage-return

A requirement for a school assignment I have asks that when a carriage return (\r) is entered as an input, it is used to halt the program: "if only a carriage-return is entered, halt the program". I've tried several things, but am stumped as to the solution.

Below are the options I've checked, all of which fail the running tests.

```
while input != '':

while input != '\r':

while input != '\n':
```

Thanks!

Comment: is input a string from another variable? or are you trying to detect a carriage return during data entry?  Thanks.

Comment: @arcee123 it is a variable which holds an input, or input = input("Enter a choice to get (r)ange, (p)ercent, or nothing to stop: ").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` is a function.  You have to write `input()`.

However, I assume you are actually trying to read information from the user, and exit if they entered nothing.  Your statement `while input() != '':` won't do that, because if they enter something useful, it will be thrown away.  You haven't stored it.

You PROBABLY want something like:

```
while 1:
    line = input()
    if not line:
        break
    # Now use the contents of line.
```

Comment: That worked! I'm sorry to ask, but why is it that inputing the carriage return makes line == False?

Comment: Too tricky of me.  When you just input Enter, input() returns an empty string.  In Python, an empty string is one of the thing that evaluates False.  Same with 0, an empty list [], and an empty dict {}.